# Multiple subscribers error using an ActorPublisher source and a reconnecting WebSocketClientFlow

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, actor, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP to connect an **Actor** with a **WebSocket** client. The actor implements `ActorPublisher[A]` and publishes instances of `A` to a source, which is read in a client WebSocket flow.

```
class Actor(...) extends Actor with ActorPublisher[A]
```

The code that builds the flow is the following:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

val actor = ...

// This method gets the actor and builds its the Akka Source
// Then opens the WebSocket using that source
def connect(): Unit = {
    val publisher = ActorPublisher[A](actor)
    val source = Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
    openWebSocket(source)
}

def openWebSocket(source: Source[A, NotUsed]): Unit = {
    val flow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest(URL))
    val (response, closed) = source
        .map { instanceOfA =>
            // Transform the instances of A to a message to send it through the websocket
            TextMessage(instanceOfA.asJson)
        }
        .viaMat(flow)(Keep.right)
        // Simple sink to print all incoming messages
        .toMat(Sink.foreach {
            case message: TextMessage.Strict => println(message.text)
        })(Keep.both)
        .run()

    // Reconnect if the socket is closed
    closed.foreach { _ =>
        connect()
    }
}
```

A `webSocketClientFlow` is built with the actor source and a simple non-related sink. It works great until the socket is closed. At that moment, the `connect` method is called again. It builds another **source** from the same agent and creates a new WebSocket flow. The problem is that the closed WebSocket flow is **still subscribed** to the actor and I get the following error creating the new one:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActorPublisher only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.12)
    at akka.stream.impl.ReactiveStreamsCompliance$.rejectAdditionalSubscriber(ReactiveStreamsCompliance.scala:59)
    at akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher.aroundReceive(ActorPublisher.scala:312)
    at akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher.aroundReceive$(ActorPublisher.scala:272)
    ...
```

How can I tell the old flow or source to **unsubscribe** from the agent? I'm currently stopping the agent and replacing it with a new one, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Not quite an explanation to the issue you are seeing, but ActorPublisher has been deprecated since Akka 2.5.0 so I'd recommend not using it for new solutions. For interactions with actors you can use Source.actorRef or Source.queue instead (this might make the semantics more clear and avoid the problem you are having as well).

Comment: `Source.actorRef` seems a very good solution for my case. Thank you!